# Upload multiple files and store into a database from ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have this method to upload files & insert folder name into database. The upload into the folder is working, but the insert into the database fails - I get this error

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Image' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Code:

```
if (files != null)
{
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        if (file.Length > 0)
        {
            //Getting FileName
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

            //Assigning Unique Filename (Guid)
            var myUniqueFileName = Convert.ToString(Guid.NewGuid());

            //Getting file Extension
            var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);

            // concatenating  FileName + FileExtension
            var newFileName = String.Concat(myUniqueFileName, fileExtension);

            // Combines two strings into a path.
            var filepath =  new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", "Image")).Root + $@"\{newFileName}";

            using (FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Create(filepath))
            {
                file.CopyTo(fs);
                fs.Flush();
            }
            image.file= fileName;
            _context.Add(image);
           await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

My EF class `Image`:

```
public partial class Image
{
    public int ImageId { get; set; }
    public string ImageName { get; set; }
    public string ImageContentType { get; set; }
    public byte[] ImageData { get; set; }
    public bool? IsDelete { get; set; }
    public bool? ImageCover { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It means you the primary key for Image table is autogenerated. You might be setting something on the value of the id?

Comment: Can you post your EF Core configuration for `Image`?

Comment: Can you try and add [Key] on top of int ImageId?

Comment: @AlvinAlmodal i am adding both of this [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]

Comment: Question title is kind of misleading. Seems to me that the problem is EF, not file upload.

Comment: @taiielmehdi don't set the value of ImageId.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your entity:

```
public partial class Image
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ImageId { get; set; }
    public string ImageName { get; set; }
    public string ImageContentType { get; set; }
    public byte[] ImageData { get; set; }
    public bool? IsDelete { get; set; }
    public bool? ImageCover { get; set; }
}
```

There is also the following option:

```
_context.Database.OpenConnection();
try
{
    _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Images ON");
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Images OFF");
}
finally
{
    _context.Database.CloseConnection();
}
```

Source: [https://entityframeworkcore.com/saving-data-identity-insert#:~:text=When%20you%20have%20a%20primary,before%20calling%20SaveChanges()%20manually](https://entityframeworkcore.com/saving-data-identity-insert#:%7E:text=When%20you%20have%20a%20primary,before%20calling%20SaveChanges()%20manually).